# Is there a way to use breakpoint in eclipse android, the same we use breakpoint in Visual Studio or Netbeans?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I have tried to use breakpoint in the same way we use break point in Visual Studio or Netbeans, we simply mark the break point and when statement executes, the breakpoint highlights and we can see the values in respective data structure or variable using breakpoint explore.
As far as i have used eclipse, i have found break point is there too, but it is not in that way, means on runtime it does not pick the respective point and neither i can see values nor the application works perfectly while doing that. Is it not possible in eclipse or some tool is required, or i am wrong, please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a breakpoint at you code line you want, 
then right click on project-> debug as -> android application

then go to window menu -> show view -> other... -> debug

or as show bellow

[image]

Comment: How to mark a breakpoint, i have opened this bug sign debug mode but i cant find mark breakpoint option.

Comment: open your java code, click on desired line then control + shift + B

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl+Shift+B** while on the line.

**Double click** on the left most bar in Editor View.

**Right click > Toggle Breakpoints** on the left most bar in Editor View.

[image: Right click on the left most bar in the Editor view to toggle Breakpoints]

Answer (score 0):

You must set a breakpoint and run the application in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch application in Debug Mode. You can find Debug button left to Run button. It has bug as an icon.

Also could be useful: [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up). It describes how to enable debugging on your device

Comment: It is simple. Just double click or right click on corresponding line number. it is in the left of code edit area.